# ruby string encoding

Tags: ruby, utf-8, character-encoding, nokogiri, iso-8859-1

So, I'm trying to do some screen scraping off of [a certain site](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/) using nokogiri, but the site owners failed to specify the proper encoding of the page in a `<meta>` tag.  The upshot of this is that I'm trying to deal with strings that think they're utf-8, but really aren't.

(If you care, here are the files I was using to test this:

- main file: http://dpaste.de/nif5/
- ann.html: http://dpaste.de/YsLM/
- ann2.html: http://dpaste.de/Lofi/
- ann3.html: http://dpaste.de/R21j/
- a-p.html: http://dpaste.de/O9dy/
- output: http://dpaste.de/WdXc/

)

After doing a lot of searching around ([this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1893064/clean-up-strange-encoding-in-ruby) was particularly useful), I found that calling `encode('iso-8859-1', 'utf-8')` on that test string "works", in that I get a proper © symbol.  The issue now is that there are other characters in some other strings I want that really do not work at being converted to latin encoding (`Shōta`, for instance, turns into `Sh�\x8Dta`).

Now, I'm probably going to bother the appropriate webmasters and try and get them to fix their damn encodings, but in the meantime, I'd like to be able to use the bytes that I've got.  I'm fairly certain that there is a way, but I just can't for the life of me figure out what it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the issue is that ANN only specifies encoding via headers, and Nokogiri doesn't receive the headers from the open() function.  So, Nokogiri guesses that the page is latin-encoded, and produces strings that we really can't reverse to get back the original characters from.

You can specify the encoding to Nokogiri as the 3rd parameter to Nokogiri::HTML(), which solves the issue I was initially trying to solve.  So, I'll accept this answer, even though the more specific question I asked (how to get those non-latin characters out of a latin string) is unanswerable.

Answer (score 1):

Those pages appear to be correctly encoded as UTF-8.  That's how my browser sees them, and when I viewsource them and tell the editor to decode them as UTF-8, they look fine.  The only problem I see is that some copyright symbols seem to have been corrupted before (or as) they were added to the content.  The o-macron and other non-ASCII letters come through just fine.

I don't know if you're aware of this, but the proper way to notify clients of a page's encoding is through a header.  Pages *may* include that information in `<meta>` tags, but that's neither required nor expected; browsers typically ignore such tags if the header is present.

Since your pages are XHTML, they could also embed the encoding information in an XML processing instruction, but again, they're not required to.  But it als means you could have Nokogiri treat them as XML instead of HTML, in which case I would expect it to use UTF-8 by default.  But I'm not familiar with Nokogiri, so I can't be sure.  And anyway, the header is still the final authority.

Comment: Yes indeed, Firefox reports that the page is utf-8 encoded, and it views just fine.  The issue is that when I pull strings out of it, they seem to be some odd latin-encoded-but-including-unicode-characters encoding, which is rather annoying, and utterly confusing.  When using a local copy of the file, adding the appropriate <meta> tag fixed this, but I wasn't sure why this would be if the server is already sending utf-8 headers. :/